# Periodic matrices in SL(3,Z)

Tags: linear-algebra, gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Periodic matrices in SL(3,Z) will be conjugated to
product of periodic matrices in SL(2,Z) by +- indentity on a third
integer direction.  Is this true?

---

Sorry, following your comments, maybe something I said is misleading. I state the original question:
   Consider a periodic automorphism $\phi$ on $Z^3$, can we find a coordinate on $Z^3$, such that $\phi$ is either  (1,0;0,A) 
 or (-1,0;0,A).

Comment: Note that such a matrix has order $1,2,3,4$ or $6$, and has $1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Conjugate in what?

Comment: @HW: conjugate in SL(3,Z)

Comment: @Geoff: I just know in SL(2,Z), periodic matrix always is conjugate
to one of the following seven cases: (1,0;1,0); (-1,0;0,-1); (0,1;-1,-1); (0,1;-1,0); (0,-1;1,1); (1,0;0,-1);(1,1;0,-1). the order of such matrices just is $1,2,3,4,6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, let me expand Geoff's suggestion. Let $A\in SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ be such that $A^n=Id$ for some positive integer $n$. Since the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a cubic polynomial of the form $-t^3+\cdots +1$, it has a positive real root; and since all roots of $A$ are roots of the unit, 1 is an eigenvalue of $A$. Moreover, since $A^n=Id$, $A$ is semisimple over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and so its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of the form $(t-1)p(t)$ with $p(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ a cyclotomic polynomial of degree at most 2 with $p(1)\neq 0$. This leaves only the following possibilities: $1$, $t+1$, $t^2+t+1$, $t^2+1$ or $t^2-t+1$, corresponding to $A$ having period $1,2,3,4$ or $6$ respectively. The period 1 case is trivial. For the period 6 case one can work as follows: we have a splitting of $\mathbb{Q}^3$ as $V\oplus W$, where $V$ and $W$ are $A$-stable $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, with $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(V)\geq 1$ and with $A$ acting as the identity on $V$. Moreover, since $p(1)=1$, we can find polynomials $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ such that $a(t)p(t)+b(t)(t-1)=1$. This implies that $\mathbb{Z}^3=(\mathbb{Z}^3\cap V)\oplus (\mathbb{Z}^3\cap W)$. The abelian subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^3\cap V$ of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is free since subgroups of free abelian groups are free, and has rank $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}V$, since $V$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^3$. So we can find a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $B_V$ for $\mathbb{Z}^3\cap V$ consisting of $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}V$ elements. The same for $\mathbb{Z}^3\cap W$. The two basis $B_V$ and $B_W$ together are a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and up to multiplying by $-1$ one of the vectors in this basis we may assume that the change of basis matrix $P$ from the standard basis of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to the basis $B_V\cup B_W$ is an element of $SL(3;\mathbb{Z})$. By construction, $PAP^{-1}$ is a block-diagonal matrix in $SL(3;\mathbb{Z})$, with an upper $1\times 1$ block $(1)$ and a lower $2\times 2$ block in $SL(2;\mathbb{Z})$.

This method, however, clearly does not apply to the remaining three cases.

Comment: 1) I guess $A$ in the 2nd sentence should be 3x3. 2) I don't see that such $a,b$ actually exist. Take $A$ the permutation matrix of the cycle (123). Its minimal polynomial is $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, i.e. $p(t) = x^2+x+1$ and $p(1) = 3$. 

Comment: Hi Ralph. Sure, what a stupid mistake! I was confused by $p(0)$ while writing. I'll now edit my answer and correct that. Thanks.

Comment: The finite subgroups of $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ are well-known: See Tahara's paper http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.nmj/1118798212. The only open case is the permutation matrix in my comment to Tom's answer. 

Comment: Is not also the following order 4 matrix from Tahara's paper
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&1\\
0&0&-1\\
0&1&0
}
$$

an open case with respect to this MO question?

Comment: Yes, I would say it is. 

Comment: @domenico and @Ralph: you mean such a example is a conterexample? how you see that?  

Comment: @domenico and @Ralph: I'm sure that such a matrix isn't a counterexample. 

Comment: Well, it is true that the $3$-dimensional representation of the cyclic group of order $3$ obtained by representing a generator by a permutation matrix associated to a $3$-cycle is indecomposable as an integral representation, because its reduction (mod $3$) is projective and necessaily indecomposable. Hence, even in `${\rm GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$`, such a matrix is not equivalent to a decomposable matrix.

Comment: Geoff, thanks for conferming. Do you have an idea, if that permutation matrix could be contained in the group $U_2$ (defined in my second comment in Tom's answer) ? 

Comment: Yes, I think that the group $U_2$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $S_4.$ It contains a Klien 4 group consisting of all diagonal matrices with entries $1$ or $-1$ and determinant $1$. Now take $A = B$ to be a matrix of order $4$ of the form $0,-1;1,0$. The $A,B$ and the given Klein $4$-group generate a group isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$, which contains a $3$-cycle permutation matrix.

Comment: I mean $A 0;0 1$ and $1 0;0 B$ together with that Klein 4-group generate a subgroup isomorphic to $S_4.$

Comment: The copy of $S_4$ is the group of all integral monomial matrices of determinant $1$ (recall that momonmial matrices have one non-zero entry in each row and one non-zero entry in each column). The Klein $4$-group is normal, and the factor group is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: Nice argument. Thank you very much. In fact 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

The matrix

$0\ 1\ 0$

$1\ 0\ 0$

$0\ 0 \-1$

in $SL_3(\mathbb Z)$ is not conjugate to any block sum of an $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ matrix and $+1$. And of course it is not conjugate to any block sum of an $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ matrix and $-1$, either.

For $GL_3$ and $GL_2$ the answer is yes.

EDIT  This last statement is wrong; see Geoff Robinson's comments.

Comment: I'm not sure how the question is to be interpreted: Are only products of matrices of one of the following two form as
are allowed or of either form ? 
$$\begin{pmatrix} A &  \\  & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\quad\quad
\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  \\  & A \end{pmatrix}$$
In the first case a simple counterexample is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$. In the latter case, however, the problem seems to be harder. 

Comment: @Ralph: You can conjugate the matrices. Shouldn't that help?

Comment: @Tom: To me, this example isn't a counterexample. 

Comment: @Ralph: Yes, both are OK. 

Comment: @Will: I just wanted to point out that it was possible to interped the question in its original version in two ways, namely: Is every periodic matrix from $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$-conjugate to a matrix of the group $U_i$ where 
$$U_1 = \langle \begin{pmatrix} A &  \\  & 1 \end{pmatrix} \mid A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \rangle$$
$$U_2 = \langle \begin{pmatrix} A &  \\  & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  \\  & B \end{pmatrix}\mid A, B \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \rangle$$
In the meanwhile the OP has clarified that he is interested in $U_1$ (I think the $U_2$-case would be harder). 

Comment: @ Bin Yu: It is true that every periodic automorphism of $\mathbb Z^3$ appears as $(1,0;0,A)$ or $(-1,0;0,A)$ for some two by two matrix $A$. It is not true that if the automorphism has determinant one then $A$ can be chosen to have determinant one.

Comment: @Tom: A permutation matrix of a $3$-cycle is not conjugate within ${\rm GL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ to a decomposable matrix, as explained in my comment on the accepted solution.

Comment: An easier way to say it would be that (mod 3), the permutation matrix of a 3-cycle has minimum polynomial `$(x-1)^3$`, so its Jordan form is a single Jordan block of size $3,$ which is indecomposable.